Trying to deserialize class with Font and get : Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor
Using System.Text.Json, I have a class with some properties including System.Drawing.Font properties.
There's no problem serializing it, but i can't deserialize it.
I Get the error Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor
Here is a simplified example :
When i click button1, i serialize the object, but i get the error when i click button2 to deserialize.
using System.Text.Json;
namespace WinFormsApp1;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private CasaSettings _casaSettings;
    private string _stringJson;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _casaSettings = new CasaSettings();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _casaSettings.DefaultFont = textBox1.Font;
        _stringJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_casaSettings, _casaSettings.GetType());
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CasaSettings convertedSetting = (CasaSettings)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(_stringJson, typeof(CasaSettings));
    }
}

public class CasaSettings 
{
    public CasaSettings() { }

    public int AlertIntervalRefresh { get; set; } = 60000;

    public Font DefaultFont { get; set; } = new Font("Tahoma", (float)8.25, GraphicsUnit.Point);
}

I need to continue using System.Text.Json.
I think i need to use a converter but can't make it work.
Thanks

Don't forget to tag your question with a language ([tag:c#]).

JSON.net: how to deserialize without using the default constructor?

Just saying that there are some solutions when its a class that you have control over. In my case i can't modify Font... nor use inheritence since its sealed

Many WinForms primitive types such as Font, Color and Icon have builtin type converters, used by Windows Forms Designer, that convert the types from and to a string representation.  You can use these type converters inside a custom JsonConverter<T> to serialize these types to JSON as strings:
public class TypeDescriptorJsonConverter<TValue> : JsonConverter<TValue>
{
    static TypeConverter TypeConverter { get; } = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TValue));
    static bool IsNonNullableValueType { get; } = typeof(TValue).IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TValue)) == null;

    public override TValue? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        reader.TokenType switch
        {
            JsonTokenType.Null when IsNonNullableValueType => throw new JsonException(),
            JsonTokenType.Null => default,
            JsonTokenType.String => (TValue?)TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(null, reader.GetString()!),
            _ => throw new JsonException()
        };

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TValue? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value is null)
            writer.WriteNullValue();
        else
            writer.WriteStringValue(TypeConverter.ConvertToInvariantString(null, value));
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonSerializerOptions AddWellKnownTypeDescriptorConverters(this JsonSerializerOptions options) 
    {
        options.Converters.Add(new TypeDescriptorJsonConverter<System.Drawing.Color>());
        options.Converters.Add(new TypeDescriptorJsonConverter<System.Drawing.Font>());
        // Add any others as required e.g.
        //options.Converters.Add(new TypeDescriptorJsonConverter<System.Drawing.Icon>());
        return options;
    }
}

Then define JsonSerializerOptions for your Form1 e.g. as follows:
readonly JsonSerializerOptions _options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    // Add whatever other options you want here, e.g.:
    WriteIndented = true,
}.AddWellKnownTypeDescriptorConverters();

And use them as follows:
_stringJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_casaSettings, _options);
CasaSettings convertedSetting = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CasaSettings>(_stringJson, _options);

Your JSON will look like (with a public Color Color { get; set; } property added for testing):
{
  "AlertIntervalRefresh": 60000,
  "DefaultFont": "Tahoma, 8.25pt",
  "Color": "AliceBlue"
}

Alternatively you could switch to Json.NET which supports serialization of types using an applied TypeConverter automatically.  Json.NET is the preferred JSON serializer in .NET Framework and works well in .NET Core also.
First install Newtonsoft.Json via nuget, then modify your code as follows:
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var _stringJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_casaSettings, Formatting.Indented);
CasaSettings convertedSetting = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CasaSettings>(_stringJson);

Your CasaSettings will round-trip to JSON without needing to create any custom converters.  The JSON format will be the same as the System.Text.Json format shown above.
